# Handling "state refresh" in Flink ConnectedStream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We're building an application which has two streams:

1. A high-volume messages stream
2. A large static stream (originating from some parquet files we have lying around) which we feed into Flink just to get that Dataset into a saved state

We want to connect the two streams in order to get shared state, so that the 1st stream can use the 2nd state for enrichment.

Every day or so, the parquet files (2nd streams's source) are updated, and that will require us to clear the state of the 2nd stream and rebuild it (will probably take about 2 minutes).

The question is, can we block/delay messages from the 1st stream while this process is running?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no direct/easy way to block one stream on another stream, unfortunately. The typical solution is to buffer the ingest stream while you load (or re-load) the enrichment stream.

One approach you could try is to wrap your ingest stream in a custom `SourceFunction` that knows when to not generate data, based on some external trigger (which is the same signal you'd use to know that you have Parquet data to re-load).

Comment: I tried writing a "RichParallelSourceFunction" which proved to be a bit more complicated than initially expected as each parquet file seemed to be read over and over again. The buffering idea seems like a good approach, and I'll probably explore this in the near future using windowing, but for now, we've decided to start with something that is as simple as possible, even if it means we'll have to start the Kafka streams manually ourselves whenever we fire up our jobs. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know why each Parquet file would be read multiple times. Each file will have multiple splits read from it, so maybe that's what you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds a bit like your case is similar to [Flip-23](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-23+-+Model+Serving), which explores Model Serving in Apache Flink.

I think it all boils down to how (and if) your static stream is keyed:

- if it is keyed in a similar way as your fast data, then you can key both streams, connect them and then have access to the keyed context.
- if the static stream events are not keyed in a similar fashion maybe you should consider emitting control events which will trigger a refresh of those static files from an external source (eg s3). That's easier said than done as there is no trivial way to guarantee that all parallel instances of your fast stream will get the control event. 
  You can use `ListState` as a buffer, how you can access this though depends on the shape of your data.

It might help, if you shared a bit more info about the shape of your data (eg are you joining on a key? are you simply serving a model? other?).

Comment: Both streams are keyed by IP prefix and one of the streams uses a ListState.
I'll take a look at the model serving since there is a similarity to that use-case. Thank you.